# When a pop-up views another pop-up ngx-bootstrap BsModalRef.hide() method doesn't work nor hide the second popup

Tags: popup, ngx-bootstrap, modalpopup

I used a modal inside a modal. If the first model is opened and then closed it works with no issues. The issue arises when first model is opened, and then the second modal is opened without closing the first. When the second modal is closed the first modal (which calls to open second modal) won't be closed by `bsModalRef.hide()`.